# Calculating the charge per unit of lenght of a cylinder

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, gauss-law

The internal cylinder of the figure is made of a non-conducting material and has a volumetric charge distribution given by $\mu (R)=C/R$, where $C=200nC/m^2$. The exterior cylinder is made of metal and both cylinders are infinitely long.

[image: cilinders]

I want to calculate the value of the electric field for all values of $R$ (the radius) using Gauss law. And I know how to do that. However, I am also asked to calculate the charge per unit of lenght of the internal cylinder, how can I calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \int_0^{3 cm} \int_0^{2\pi} \mu(r) rd\theta dr = \int_0^{3 cm} 2\pi \frac{C}{r} r dr = 2\pi C\cdot 3cm =  $$
$$2\pi \cdot 2\cdot  10^{-7}[\frac{C}{m^2}]\cdot 3\cdot 10^{-2}[m] = 12\pi \cdot 10^{-9} [\frac{C}{m}]$$

Comment: Could you explain why you calculate this? $ \int_0^{3 cm} \int_0^{2\pi} \mu(r) rd\theta dr$

Comment: Because I need to add all the charges at a single plane, do you understand me? :)

Comment: But why don't you need the length of the cylinder?

Comment: Because I don't want the total charge, only the total charge for an infinitesimal unit of length, meaning I need to integrate the charge density on a single plane, without a third integral $ \int dz $